# Does it make sense to order condition in where query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, clustered-index, query-performance

We have a clustered index in table Tbl with order of A,B,C.
Does it make senses to write a query to have

```
WHERE A = @a, B = @b, C = @c
```

or it'll be as same as

```
WHERE C = @c, B = @b, A = @a
```

Does the order of query make sense for clustered index?

Comment: And you have to use `AND`, not commas, between the conditions in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes no difference: the optimiser evaluates the query and will work out predicate order for itself, matching a suitable index and all the other good stuff it does.

This is because SQL is "declarative" not "procedural": you say what you want, not how to do it.

It's nicer to read though...

Answer (score -3):

Actually when we use the where clase then sql creates seperate pages for each where clause. then its make join based on AND , OR and then produce the output. So, here switching the where clause is not a matter.